# Python: Iterate through Big Array with BigInts, find first duplicate and printout the indexes of the duplicate Values

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, duplicates

for Cryptographie course in my university i need to compare a lot of SHA Hashes which are saved in an array. I need to compare the values of the Array Indexes.

There are duplicates in the Array - i already checked that with a comparison between the length of a set of the array and the length of the array itself.

Now i need to have the indexes of the duplicated values. I found a lot of solutions for checking for duplicates, but only for short arrays. My Array has a length of 3 Million and the Values in each index are around this length: 864205495604807476120572616017955259175325408501.

I have written a nested loop (coming from Java and trying to learn python). Here my code:

```
counter_outer = 0
while counter_outer < len(hash_value_array):
    counter_inner = counter_outer + 1
    while counter_inner < len(hash_value_array):
        if hash_value_array[counter_outer] == hash_value_array[counter_inner]:
            print(f"*****FOUND MATCH *****")
            print(f"Message [{counter_outer}] Hashvalue has same Value as Message [{counter_inner}]")
            safe_index1 = counter_outer
            safe_index2 = counter_inner
            counter_outer = len(hash_value_array)
            break
        else:
            print("------NO Match-----")
        counter_inner += 1
    counter_outer += 1
```

As you can imagine ... this takes ages.

Important for me is, **that i need the indexes where the duplicates are** - not the values. So for example, if there is a 898 in index 100 and a 898 in index 1000001 i only need as output: 100, 1000001

Any suggestions?

Comment: "Any suggestions?" - Yes, show us good complete example input and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something along these lines in Python:

Assume this list of 5 signatures (they could be ints or strings, but I have strings):

```
li=['864205495604807476120572616017955259175325408501',
'864205495604807476120572616017955259175325408502',
'864205495604807476120572616017955259175325408503',
'864205495604807476120572616017955259175325408501',
'864205495604807476120572616017955259175325408502']
```

You can make a dict of lists with each list being the index of duplicates:

```
idx={}
for i, sig in enumerate(li):
    idx.setdefault(sig, []).append(i)
```

If you make `li` 3,000,000 entries, that runs in about 550 milliseconds on my computer and likely would be similar on yours.

You can then find the duplicates like so:

```
for sig, v in idx.items():
    if len(v)>1:
        print(f'{sig}: {v}')
```

Prints:

```
864205495604807476120572616017955259175325408501: [0, 3]
864205495604807476120572616017955259175325408502: [1, 4]
```

If you just want the FIRST duplicate, you can modify the first loop like so:

```
idx={}
for i, sig in enumerate(li):
    if sig in idx:
        print(f'Duplicate {sig} at {idx[sig]} and {i}')
        break 
    else:
        idx[sig]=i
```

Prints:

```
Duplicate 864205495604807476120572616017955259175325408501 at 0 and 3
```

---

*But to be honest - i dont understand why this is so much faster.*

Yours is super slow because it has `O n**2` complexity from nested `while` loops. You are looping over the entire array for each element. The method I showed you here is only looping once over the entire list -- not 3 million times!

Comment: But where does it check if its a duplicate in the code?

Comment: @fancyStuff90: I added that. Thanks.

Comment: WoW Thank you! Thats magic - my code was after around 2 hours @ iterating array index 200/3000000. Yours did that in seconds - awesome man. I voted your answer, but it seems i´m to "low" that its shown :( But again - thanks! But to be honest - i dont understand why this is so much faster.

Comment: @fancyStuff90: I answered your question with an edit. It is the nested while loops that makes yours so slow. Read about [Big O](https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation) to understand computational complexity.